# tf.print from TF2 not printing to output

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TF2 and I would like to print the tensor inside a function running in a tf.data.Dataset pipeline.

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

sys.stdout = open('tf.log', 'w')

def main():

    ## Dataset generator
    #
    numRows= 100

    indx = tf.reshape([i+1 for i in range(numRows)], [numRows,1])
    features = tf.random.uniform([numRows, 2], minval=1, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)

    myData = tf.concat([indx, features], 1)

    ## tf.data.Dataset
    #
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(myData)

    ## Pipeline
    #
    dataset.map(myFunc)

    ## Run pipeline
    #
    for d in dataset:
        print('--')

def myFunc(t):
    tf.print(t, output_stream=sys.stdout)
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But as result, I'm getting only this:

```
--
--
--
--
--
--
--
--
--
--
--
```

How can I use `tf.print` to print the tensors to the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the dataset returned by `map` to anything. Simply do,

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(myData)
dataset = dataset.map(myFunc)
```

Comment: I don't see answer to why `tf.print` is not printing anything